# Linux merge sort is *slower* that full sort?

Tags: linux, sorting, merge

I'm using Linux merge sort (sort -m) to sort a large group of presorted files. I was assuming that merge sort would be considerably faster than a full sort on the unsorted data but that's not what I'm seeing. For example, if I do a full sort on 1000 files containing 10000 lines of unsorted data:

```
/bin/time -o ./full_sort.time -v sort --parallel 8 -k1,1g ./data/unsorted/f* > /dev/null
```

I see the following times:

```
User time (seconds): 104.70
System time (seconds): 0.71
Percent of CPU this job got: 440%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:23.90
```

Now, if I presort the data and run the exact same sort while invoking the -m option:

```
/bin/time -o ./merge_sort.time -v sort --parallel 8 -k1,1g -m ./data/presorted/f* > /dev/null
```

I see these times:

```
User time (seconds): 59.34
System time (seconds): 2.15
Percent of CPU this job got: 99%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 1:01.60
```

The merge sort wall time is actually *slower* than the full sort! Again, I was expecting the merge sort to be considerably faster since each input file in the data set is presorted and only the merge step remains to be done. There must be a something that I'm missing. Can someone please clarify what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
JCS

Comment: Does this fix the performance of merge? `/bin/time -v sort -k1,1g --batch-size=1000 -m ./data/presorted/f* > /dev/null
` ?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7335920/10765659). Your results suggest maybe the merge sort was choking on I/O. Full sort must read all the input files, then process data. Reading whole files in sequence can be relatively fast. Merge sort is to reduce memory usage, not time. To minimize memory usage, at any given time `sort` needs to memorize just one line per file (this may be somewhat simplified, but basically true). But then it needs to jump from file to file and read next lines in a scattered manner. What is the filesystem? the hardware? There may be more factors.